# How to access list.Element.Value's own property in Golang?

Tags: go

Using `container/list`, it's easy to make object managing listed elements, and access each element sequentially.

But it seems each element.Value cannot allow to access it's own property derived from user defined type, because the type of `element.Value` is `interface{}`

```
for p := members.Front(); p != nil; p = p.Next() {
    fmt.Printf("This is Person -> %+v\n", p.Value)
    fmt.Printf("This is also `Person` -> %T\n\n", p.Value)
    // fmt.Printf("But cannnot access Person.Name %s\n", p.Value.Name)
}
```

(whole code here: http://play.golang.org/p/AMWqdPymHq)

How can I access element.Value's own property, or apply the type while constructing list object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you know that the list contains `Person` values, you can retrieve that value from the `interface{}` variable using a type assertion:

```
person := p.Value.(Person)
```

You now have full access to the value and can access its fields.  Note that `person` is a copy of the value stored in `p.Value`, so modifying `person` will not modify the value item in the list.  You can work around this by either (a) assigning the modified `person` back to `p.Value` or (b) store `*Person` pointers in the list.

If list item does not contain a `Person` value, the above code will panic.  That's fine if you know the list will always contain values of that type.  Otherwise, you can use the two-return type assertion syntax:

```
person, ok := p.Value.(Person)
```

Which will instead set `ok` to `false` if the type doesn't match.  For more complex cases, you can also use a [type switch](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_switches).